# How can I make interative linked list function to recursive

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I am having this issue on finding the way to make an iterative function a recursive one.

It is about a linked list, this linked list stores "favorites" videos, each video has a sound, and we want to count all videos that contains a specified sound.

Linked list elements looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    tVideo video;    
} tFavorite; 

// Data type to hold data related to a video in the platform
typedef struct tNode {
    tFavorite e;
    struct tNode *next;
} tFavoriteStackNode;

// Definition of a stack of favorites
typedef struct {
    tFavoriteStackNode *first;
} tFavoriteStack;
```

And tVideo has a sound (video.sound).

Right now, the iterative function is like this:

```
unsigned favoriteStack_getFavoritesPerSoundRecursive(tFavoriteStack *stack, tSound *sound){
    // PR2 EX3
    assert(stack != NULL);
    tFavoriteStackNode *tmp = (tFavoriteStackNode*)malloc(sizeof(tFavoriteStackNode));
    static int cont = 0;
    if (favoriteStack_empty(*stack)) {
        return cont;
    }
    else {
        tmp = stack->first;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            if (tmp->e.video.sound != NULL){
                if (sound_equals(sound, tmp->e.video.sound)){
                    cont++;
                }
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

In this case, we make a while loop and change the node to the next every time.
*(Note that `if (tmp->e.video.sound != NULL)`  is called because of an assertion in the sound_equals())*

So my question is how could I make this function into a recursive one?

Thanks in advance,

Joan Freixas

Comment: Making it (tail) recursive involves deciding whether the current entry matches, and if not calling the function recursively on the next item in the list, returning the status of that recursive call.  You'll need to decide what to return; a count is unusual for lists.

Comment: A recursive solution requires passing the first `tNode` to a function and then passing the next node to the same function in a recursive call. You will also need a base condition to decide when to stop the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned tFavoriteStackNode_numSoundRecursive (
    tFavoriteStackNode *node, 
    tSound *sound
){
    if (node == NULL) // stop recursion
        return 0;
        
    // assuming sound_equals returns a boolean value (0: false, 1: true)
    // need something different if a e.g. -1 could be returned in case of some error
    unsigned eq = (node->e.video.sound != NULL) 
                  ? sound_equals(sound, node->e.video.sound) 
                  : 0;
    return (
        eq +
        tFavoriteStackNode_numSoundRecursive (
            node->next, 
            sound
        )
    );
}
        
unsigned favoriteStack_getFavoritesPerSoundRecursive (
    tFavoriteStack *stack, 
    tSound *sound
){
    assert(stack != NULL);
    
    if (favoriteStack_empty(*stack)) //sure about dereferencing?
        return 0;
        
    return tFavoriteStackNode_numSoundRecursive(stack->first);
}
```

@Code Apprentice - the recursion was terminated too early, i realized that, now it should be right.

Comment: This is recursive, but doesn't do the same thing as the OP's iterative solution.